# how to select column values to display in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am using pandas 0.16.0, I have data:

```
id A  B
1  10 100
2  10 101
3  20 102
```

when I call

```
df.groupby(['A']).groups
```

I have

```
{10: [1 2], 20: [3]}
```

and I want to have this (values from column B)

```
{10: [100, 101], 20: [102]}
```

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to groupby and apply function to take list, and then convert to dict.

```
In [92]: df.groupby(['A']).apply(lambda x: x['B'].tolist()).to_dict()
Out[92]: {10: [100, 101], 20: [102]}
```